# Как запустить golang скрипт из golang скрипта?

Tags: golang

Всем привет, очень интересно как запустить скрипт из скрипта, это два отдельных файла которые лежат в отдельных директориях, возможно ли такое? может golang может воздействовать на консоль?

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий. Берёте [`os/exec`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/) и запускаете. В чём проблема?

Answer (score 3):

Golang умеет взаимодействовать с консолью, например с помощью пакета os/exec

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd, _ := exec.Command("go", "test", "../.").Output() // В данном случае я запускаю тесты из пакета выше, и с помощью Output вывожу что прилетело в ответ на вызов этой команды
    fmt.Println(string(cmd))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/containous/yaegi/interp"
    "github.com/containous/yaegi/stdlib"
)

func main() {
    i := interp.New(interp.Options{})

    i.Use(stdlib.Symbols)

    _, err := i.Eval(`import "fmt"`)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    _, err = i.Eval(`fmt.Println("Hello Yaegi")`)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

https://github.com/containous/yaegi