# Как из скомпилированного Golang скрипта скомпилировать GoLang скрипт?

Tags: golang

Грубо говоря:
У меня есть программа на golang, в ней генерируется код GoLang как строка, мне нужно скомпилировать этот код\строку (+библиотеки) в исполняемый файл.

Comment: то есть, Вам нужен компилятор Go внутри бинарника? Возможно, Вы делаете что то не то. Можете чуточку больше написать о исходной проблеме, а не о том, как Вы ее пытаетесь решить?

Comment: @KoVadim, грубо говоря - да, я хочу компилировать бинарник. Можно и альтернативный путь, у меня скаченный исходный код, а внутри скомпилированого скрипта GoLang будет библиотека, как бы портативная версия golang компилятора, и вот она будет компилировать этот исходный код

Comment: Вы рассказываете о том, как Вы видите решение своей проблемы, но не говорите об изначальной проблеме. Вкомпилить компилятор го внутрь приложения может быть достаточно нетривиально (не говоря уже о размере). Плюс ко всему, а если пользователь захочет импортировать что то, чего нет?

Comment: это не проблема, это вопрос, как это можно реализовать, возможно я не там задал его, я тут впервые, извините если что.

Comment: да не то, что не там задано. тут все ок. просто обычно, когда людям нужен компилятор внутри скомпилированого бинарника, то обычно это говорит о том, что они решают другую задачу. Например, им просто нужен парсер арифметических выражений.

Comment: Не подскажите куда задать вопрос? Буду признателен.

Comment: с такой формулировкой я даже не знаю, где Вам помогут. А мои подсказки Вы упорно игнорируете.

Comment: @Annelo вряд ли вы пишете какое-то серьёзное приложение. Значит можно  просто использовать go build. Сохраните сгенерированный код во временную папку, запустите go build. Можно завернуть это в sh-скрипт для удобства или сделать [exec](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec) непосредственно из вашей программы.

Comment: Возможно вам поможет решение
https://github.com/containous/yaegi https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1145481/186030

Answer (score 0):

Генерируем код из приложения, запускаем приложением установленный рядом компилятор go на сборку сгенерированного кода, готово.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]